# Listview recycles and shows duplicated images

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have created a listview which consists of list of tracks and play and pause image.When clicked on play image, pause image becomes visible and clicking on pause ,play image will become visible.Issue is that when i click on play and scrolls down i see another list item showing pause image and when i scroll down more another list item showing pause image.It is because list recylces an shows duplicated images.On studying the issue i think i need to place if-else statement in the getView method but i failed to implement correct code to resolve this issue..plzz help me with code in tht..

Comment: Is `SoundCloud` your own made class?

Comment: @DroidDev yeah...........

Comment: you need to manage a separate boolean array for defining the visibility of imageview, when you click on button set true for that position and set visibility out of on click method based on that boolean array value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new boolean variable in your `SoundCloud` class by the name `isPlaying`. Create getter setters for it, like you have done for other variables.

Get the object from `SoundCloudList` like this:

```
SoundCloug soundCloud = (SoundCloud) getItem(position);
```

This object can be used everywhere you are using `soundcloudList.get(position)`, so that makes it easy to because we don't have to fetch object everytime.

Then in your `getView` use `isPlaying` to show play/pause button on every position like below:

```
if(soundCloud.isPlaying()){
    holder.img1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    holder.img2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
else{
    holder.img1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    holder.img2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

and then in your `onClickListeners`, set values for `isPlaying` like this:

```
holder.img1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(final View v) {

        soundCloud.setPlaying(true);
        try {
            notifyDataSetChanged();
            holder.img1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            holder.img2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
            mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            mMediaPlayer.setDataSource("http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/" + soundcloudList.get(position).getId() + "/stream?client_id=e13865f9debacb5f96375fdd96b7fa1b");
            mMediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
            mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp)
                {
                    mp.start();

                }
            });
            mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(
                    new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp)
                        {
                            mMediaPlayer.release();
                            mMediaPlayer = null;
                            holder.img1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }
                    });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

});

holder.img2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(final View v)
    {
        soundCloud.setPlaying(false);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
        holder.img1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.img2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        if(mMediaPlayer!=null)
        {
            mMediaPlayer.release();
            mMediaPlayer = null;
        }
    }

});
```

This code will not show the play/pause button duplicated on multiple rows, because now, we are checking the play/pause of audio for every row in `getView` and only then setting the buttons visibility.

Comment: ok @user3753273 go ahead. Ping me if you need any explanation. All the best :)

Comment: check out my updated code in question which i tried as per your answer..now clicking on play button doesn't changes the image..when i scroll down and and then scroll up again image does get changed as view gets refreshed but sudio doesn't play..the issue is because the if-else loop only executes when view get refreshed not when we click on buttons..plzz let me know where i am going wrong..i have added soundcloud class also in question..i am also having problem in getting object in the way you said.."SoundCloud soundCloud = (SoundCloud) getItem(position);"..

Comment: oh..i forgot to update soundcloudadapter code in question...check out now..issue is mentioned in last comment

Comment: no @user3753273 you are doing it wrong. Please, check my updated answer. That's the right way to do it.

Comment: Thanku so muchh..one more issue that i am having is that if i click on multiple play buttons multiple audios start playing.and then if i try to pause multiple audios app crashes..how to prevent multiple audios from playing at same time?glad if you can help me with tht..

Comment: you'll need to user one and only one object media player class for that @user3753273. What I did in similar case was to create a `service` to play music and when user play another song, the first one was automatically paused, because of service using single `MediaPlayer` object. When new source was set, previous one was automatically discarded. But, that's totally different topic. I hope you get what I explained. Best of luck :)

Comment: I need to use only one object of media player class..Am i not using one object of media player class in above code?If i declare  mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(); inside getView() rather then setOnClickListener() then the audio doesn't pause on clicking on pause button.